# How can i make this an async function or a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, discord.js

i'm trying to make a discord bot. I'm using AkairoClient as a framework, within it there's an option to set a prefix. what I have is the following code:

```js
            // HANDLERS
        this.commandHandler = new CommandHandler(this, {

            prefix: msg => {
                let prefix;
                console.log('first')
                con.query(`SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = ${msg.guild.id}`, (err, rows) => {
                    if (!err) prefix = rows[0].prefix;
                    console.log('Second')
                
                });
                console.log('third')
                return prefix ?? '!';
            },
            blockBots: true,
/* Rest of code here ...*/
        });
```

When i execute this, The console prints:

- First
- Third
- First
- Third
- Second
- Second

I'm having issues understanding on how should I make this work properly as I want the `prefix` to get the value of rows, but in this instance `prefix` is returning as `undefined` before the query finishes

Comment: What is `con.query`? Doesn't the library you use support promises instead of callbacks?

Comment: i'm using MySQL node module. 
i don't think it supports it, i'm looking at MySQL2 which might.
`con` is a constant define in a line i didnt show, it's a connection to the MySQL database.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure how your modules work but this would be the correct syntax for an async await function:

```
this.commandHandler = new CommandHandler(this, {
    prefix: async msg => {
        let prefix;
        console.log('first');

        const rows = await con.query(`SELECT * FROM info WHERE id = ${msg.guild.id}`).catch(console.log);

        console.log('Second');

        if (rows) prefix = rows[0].prefix;

        console.log('third');

        return prefix ?? '!';
    },
    blockBots: true,
/* Rest of code here ...*/
});
```